# informix : dynamic condition in where clause

Tags: where-clause, informix

I want to write a query in which I would like to have condtions in the WHERE clause which are dependant on the values in the result set itself.

for example,if I have a STUDENT table with columns student_id,name,age,post_code,num_subjects_enrolled

I want to get all the names of the students living in the post_code = 'POSTCODE' and (if they take more than one subject I want to filter by age < 20 else age > 20)

I want to do all in one query .

I am using informix and any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the offered answer isn't sufficient help, then you need to clarify your question, notably in terms of 'which language are you using to write the SQL in'.  The basic technique, though, is usually to build up the query in a string, then go through the language-appropriate steps to convert that string into a working query.  The details vary from language to language, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can built it with some `AND` and `OR` logic:

```
SELECT name FROM student WHERE post_code = '12345'
AND
 (
   (num_subjects_enrolled > 1 AND age < 20)
   OR
   (num_subjects_enrolled <= 1 AND age >= 20)
 )
```